# XPath's function-available(): why do its results vary with the place in the style sheet and how can it be used to protect new

Tags: xslt, xpath, saxon

In a Java XSLT extension (for Saxon 9.1.0.8), I have written a functionality that is used by first creating a new object and the calling instance methods on it (in an XSLT 1.0 style sheet).  The following is a shortened version that exhibits the same problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="http://www.acrolinx.com" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" version="1.1" extension-element-prefixes="saxon mt" xmlns:mt="http://www.jclark.com/xt/java/com.acrolinx.xsltextensions.MTExporter">
 <xsl:variable name="exportMediaFile-available" select="function-available('mt:exportMediaFile')"/>
 <xsl:variable name="mt" select="mt:new('http', 'localhost', 8031, 'uID', 'hDB', 'o/eT', 'Mt')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:message>exportMediaFile <xsl:value-of select="function-available('mt:exportMediaFile')"/></xsl:message>
  <xsl:element name="mtf">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="a:actif/a:data/a:entry"/>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:message>finalizeExport <xsl:value-of select="function-available('mt:finalizeExport')"/></xsl:message>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:entry">
  <xsl:element name="conceptGrp">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="a:value"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:value">
  <xsl:if test="@field != ''">
    <xsl:call-template name="descrip">
      <xsl:with-param name="type" select="@field"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="content" select="saxon:evaluate('node()')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="descrip">
  <xsl:param name="type"/>
  <xsl:param name="content"/>
  <xsl:element name="descrip">
    <xsl:attribute name="type">
      <xsl:value-of select="$type"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$type = 'imageURL' and $exportMediaFile-available">
    <xsl:message>exportMediaFile <xsl:value-of select="function-available('mt:exportMediaFile')"/></xsl:message>
    <xsl:value-of select="mt:exportMediaFile($mt, $content)"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$content"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Questions:

- I wanted to protect the calls with `function-available()`, but it seemed to return different results depending on the place in the style sheet where it (=`function-available()`, *not* the function itself) was called.
  It turns out that using `saxon:evaluate('node()')` *changes* the behaviour of `function-available`: without (i.e. as `node()`) it is working as expected, whereas with the `saxon:evaluate()` call, the `function-available()` calls return false inside the `descrip` template.  What is the reason (since the two do not seem related to me)?
- Is there any way to protect the constructor call with `function-available()`?  I cannot use `xsl:if` at the top level.  If I instantiate the variable `mt` with `<xsl:variable name="mt"><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="function-available('mt:new')"><xsl:value-of select="mt:new('http', 'localhost', 8031, 'uID', 'hDB', 'o/eT', 'Mt')"/></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="jo:new()"/></xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose></xsl:variable>`

(where jo is just the namespace for a plain Java Object - apologies for the layout, but the text remained invisible otherwise) then it works if the extension is not available.  If it is available, I get the following error:

```
    Cannot convert value class net.sf.saxon.value.TextFragmentValue of type document-node() to class com.acrolinx.xsltextensions.MTExporter
```

That already happens in fact with

```
<xsl:variable name="mt">
  <xsl:value-of select="mt:new('http', 'localhost', 8031, 'uID', 'hDB', 'o/eT', 'Mt')"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Perhaps some implicit cast is taking place, so that it works with `select`, but not with a nested `xsl:value-of`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to show some specific code that gives results you are unable to explain: if the code isn't doing what you expect, then we need to see the code in order to understand why your expectations are wrong. Ideally give a full stylesheet: context (such as the version number, namespace declarations etc) can be important.

In XSLT 2.0 I would recommend using function-available() in a use-when attribute, so that the code that calls the relevant function is masked out at compile time. The trouble about using it in xsl:if is that the function call is still visible to the compiler and will fail to resolve. XSLT 1.0 (and 2.0 in backwards compatibility mode) allow this and say that you only get an error if you actually evaluate the function call.

The message "Cannot convert value class net.sf.saxon.value.TextFragmentValue of type document-node() to ..." is not one I would normally expect to see. It might be a Saxon bug, or it might simply a rather poor diagnostic of some user error. Either way, I would like to see the details of what you did that resulted in this message.

Comment: I've updated my question with more concrete information.<br/>I think I'll move the script to XSLT 2.0 and use the use-when attribute, since it seems an elegant solution to my need.